# Correct way implementing tcp stateful server in Golang

Tags: go, tcp, connection, stateful

I believe this has been asked before but never found anything related to stateful connections, So here it goes.

I'm writting a server in golang where users connect and login to ask for specific date later on. My problem here is that doing my research I came up with a method of archiving this over a tcp connection (lets remember it's stateful) creating a goroutine every connection and keeping it listening to the user income like this example: https://github.com/firstrow/tcp_server/blob/master/tcp_server.go
My doubts with this method are related with the idea of keeping a goroutine openned for every connected user.

I would like to know if this is the correct approach or if there is another method to archieve that like keeping a less amount of routines listning for new incomes.

Thanks

Comment: Goroutines are not threads, they don't require context switching on the CPU and they're aware of IO blocking. I've had servers with more than 24k goroutines perform fine on commodity hardware.

Comment: That is the idiomatic pattern in Go, it's fine

Comment: You're meant to use goroutines for this sort of purpose.

Comment: And if you want to have control over the number of goroutines running, you can use a buffered channel that blocks as soon as a certain number of workers are "spawned".